# Restarting Galera cluster after maintence on 2 of 3 nodes

Tags: galera

I'm running a Galera Cluster using 3 nodes. I shutdown 2 of the 3 nodes to service the appliance. After restarting the 2 servers, I get errors:
"Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
"Failed to open channel 'galera_cluster' at ... lists the 2 nodes which were shutdown.

I shutdown MariaDB on the last running node, and ran command line :
galera_new_cluster
The other nodes still generate the same errors when attempting to start using
sudo systemctl start mysql

Comment: Next time, do only one node at a time.  That way, the Cluster maintains a quorum.

Comment: I ended up doing a sql backup of the remaining node, reset all nodes to 'clean' state with no data, added another 3 nodes for a total of 6, and started the new cluster, reloaded the sql databases and tables.